# How to set current value of the input using react-select multiple

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

i have problem to add current value in form for editing i use react-select multiple like this picture

[image]

and this is my code

this is the initial values

```
const initialStates = {
         drugs: [{}]
    }


    const [currentStates, setCurrentStates] = useState(initialStates);
```

this is select input using react-select

```
<Select
                                                            
name="drugs"
closeMenuOnSelect={false}
options={drugList.map((e) => ({ label: e.nom , value: e }))}
isMulti
values={currentStates.drugs}
onChange={onChange}
/>
```

and this the onChange methode

```
const onChange = selectedOptions =>{
        let drugs;
        if(drugs){
     setCurrentStates(selectedOptions)}} ;
```

my data to edit is this in the picture

[image]

The question is simple how to set current value of the input? Like when I put focus there and see already written text.

Or how to enable editing of the existing tag, that I could click and continue typing?

Comment: I didn't understand your question correctly (sorry), if you want to be able to write in the input in multi-selection you must use the "creatable" component, link: https://react-select.com/creatable

Comment: My application is a  crud(create ,edit, delete) but i have problem in edit form My question is  i want to update data in the  form  the information are already in the update form but i have problem to show the current  existing tag, that I could click and continue typing? @MB_

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property `value` not `values`